# Counting number of associations across several Rails objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Article
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :article
end
```

I'd like to be able to determine how many total comments exist for certain articles.  For example: Article #20, #21 and #22 have a total of X comments between them.

Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
Comment.where(:article_id => [20, 21, 22]).count
```

Doing the counting etc. in the database and all in one query (which ActiveRecord will, in this case) is about as efficient as possible.

Comment: +1 for thinking about the problem the other way around.  You might not know the article ids before the query in some cases, however, other than the one given, e.g. `Article.where(["created_at > ?",2.weeks.ago])`.

Comment: In the case where you've given, I'd say it was time to use a join, e.g. `Comment.joins(:article).where('articles.created_at > ?', 2.weeks.ago).count`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `counter_cache` to your `articles` table

```
class Article
  has_many :comments, :counter_cache => true
end
```

and add a `comments_count` column to your `articles` table.

(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) and then sum it as so.

`Article.where(:id => [20,21,22]).sum(:comments_count)`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this without a counter cache if you prefer.

```
Article.where(:id => [20,21,22]).joins(:comments).count
```